# Crop Sentinel-2 raster using a geometry leaves pixels around the edges

Tags: python, clip, rasterio, sentinel-2

I want to crop Sentinel-2 images using a geometry. However, whenever I crop my image, there are some pixels around the border of the raster. For example, the image below is the band 2 of sentinel-2 after cropping it. The pixels I'm talking about are the ones like the one with the red arrow.
[image]

The orange polygons in the image below represent the geometry I'm using for the cropping.
[image]

How can I remove these pixels? Is there a better way to crop my images?

This is the function I'm using for cropping the raster.

```py
def crop_region(input_path, output_path, geometry, nodata=0, extension='.jp2', type='JP2OpenJPEG', all_bands=True, bands_list=None):
    all_files = os.listdir(input_path)
    jp2_files = [file for file in all_files if file.lower().endswith(extension)]
    bands_to_run = jp2_files if all_bands else filter_strings_with_substrings(jp2_files, bands_list)

    for band in bands_to_run:
        rasterPath = os.path.join(input_path,band)
        with rasterio.open(rasterPath) as src:
            out_image, out_transform = mask(src,geometry,
                                                        crop=True,
                                                        nodata=nodata)

            out_meta = src.meta
            out_meta.update({"driver": type,
                "height": out_image.shape[1],
                "width": out_image.shape[2],
                "nodata": nodata,
                "transform": out_transform})
            outPath = os.path.join(output_path,band)
            with rasterio.open(outPath, "w", **out_meta) as dest:
                dest.write(out_image)
```

Comment: Maybe your input data is compressed with lossy JPEG2000 method and using 0 as nodata value does not quite work because lossy compression is changing zero sometimes into close values like 1 or 2. There is a GDAL utility https://gdal.org/programs/nearblack.html that tries to handle this case.

Comment: A variation on/clarification of the comment of @user30184: the input format is strictly speaking not important for those border pixels as you are applying the mask on it anyway, but make sure you save your output file to a file that is not or losslessly compressed or that the mask is saved in an uncompressed alpha channel to avoid this effect.

Comment: thank you @user30184 and pieter. i did look at the nearblack but I ended up changing  what I was doing. Instead of using the rasterio mask, I used the gdal warp and called the cutline and that fixed the issue.